# Why use separate source files?

Tags: c, include, header-files

I'm learning C, coming from scripted languages background it is highly intriguing and rather confusing.

A brief story of how I got to this question:

At first I was confused why I can't include a source (`.c`) file in another source file, then I found out that function declarations repeat. Then I found out about header files (`.h`) and was confused, why I have to declare a function in one file then define in another, then if something changes I have to go edit 2 files, so I started defining functions in header files. Then I found out that `#ifndef` doesn't work across separate source files, so here's the question I can't yet find the answer to:

Why do I even have to use separate source files? Why can't I just have 1 source file and put all of my other code/function definitions in header files, this way I'm going to have things defined once and included once in the final build?

Now don't get me wrong, I'm not thinking I'll start a revolution, I'm just looking for answers as to why this is not how it works.

Comment: You don't _have to_ use separate files. Some compilers achieve performance gains by lumping many source files together and compiling them in one chunk. But all other things being equal, smaller files are more easy for humans to read than larger ones.

I'm concerned that this post may attract primarily opinion based answers, but for now I'm interested to see what else people may have to say.

Answer (score 4):

If you think beyond small learning programs, there are several benefits to splitting code into multiple source files.

## Code Organization

Large programming projects can have *millions* of lines of code. You don't want to have files that big! Editors will probably have trouble handling it. Human beings will have trouble understanding it. Multiple developers would have conflicts all touching the same file. If you separate the code by purpose, it will be much easier to handle.

## Build Times

Many code changes are small, while compilation time can be expensive. Compilers typically work on a file at a time, not parts of files. So if you make a tiny change and then have to rebuild the entire project, that can be very time consuming. If your code is separated into multiple source files, making a change in one of them means you only have to recompile *that file*.

## Reusability

Frequently, code can be reused for more than one program. If you have all your code in one source file, you'll have to go and copy that code into another file to reuse it. Of course, now if it has a bug you have two places to fix it. Not good.

Let's say, for example, you have code that uses a linked list. If you put the linked list code into its own source file, you can then simply link that into another program. If there's a bug, you can fix it in one place, recompile, and then re-link the programs that use it.

Comment: But I think you don't understand what I mean. Defining functions in header files will still result into the program being split into multiple files, they are just not source files but header files..?

Comment: @erdegis: It won't help with build times. Header files have to be compiled along with the source files that `#include` them. Still, "header only libraries" can be useful too. C++ uses them quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single source file for some (small) projects.

For many projects though, it makes sense to divide the source in different source files according to their function.
Let's say your making a game.

Have all the user interface code in its source file.
Have all the computer move algorithms in its source file.
...
Have the `main()` function which ties it all together in its source file.

Then, to compile for PC you do `gcc game.c algo.c ui-pc.c`, to compile to android you do `gcc game.c algo.c ui-android.c` ..., to compile a brand new algorithm you though up and don't know if it's good `gcc game.c algo-test.c ui-pc.c`

---

Header files help keep everything in sync. And they're a good place for documentation.

Comment: Can you add something about header files and function declaration versus definition? This looks like a concept that OP particularly wanted to understand

Comment: I agree with @TimRandall, that's indeed what I meant also. Have all the separate code in separate files, just be it header and not source files. This way even compiling is much simpler: `gcc main.c` and you're done?

Comment: Header files are not supposed to have code (I believe C++ treats the issue differently). Reason being (mostly) that if the header file is included by 2 (or more) source files the code is being duplicated (and duplication of prototypes / types / defines is ok). Also, as the project grows ... you move from `gcc` to `make` :-)

Comment: @pmg but if I have `#ifndef` the code will not get duplicated?

Comment: `#ifndef` only helps for multiple inclusion from the same single `.c` file (maybe through a different header file). Say you have `#include "a,h"` and `#include "b.h"` ... and thet the header file `b.h` has `#include "a.h"` ... your `.c` file is protected against multiple inclusionof `a.h`. If `a.h` has **code** (is not limited to types, macros, prototypes, ...) each `.c` file that includes `a.h` will compile "its" version of that code resulting in duplication.